# Unable to retrieve user email through graph api even though have required permissions

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello I am new to facebook app development and working over my first app.

My app includes the functionality of retrieving user email, ive the required privileges and user has approved those privileges at the time of authentication but when am trying to retrieve user email through graph api am getting nothing in return however other information such as user display picture, name etc has been successfully retrieved.

at Authentication:

```
$dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . $redirect_uri . "&state=" . $_SESSION['state']."&scope=email,user_photos,publish_stream";
```

Retrieving user email:

```
$userEmail = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/' . $userId)) -> email;
echo "email: ".$userEmail;
```

Kindly help me with this.
Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL must me https:// insead of http://

And also include the access token.

```
file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/" . $userId . "/?access_token=" . $accesstoken);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add the "access token" in your request in order to "authenticate" your request call. Otherwise, only public data is returned.

Find here the steps to get this token: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Basically, if the user accept the permissions, Facebook will redirect him to the url $redirect_uri and will add a "code" parameter. With this code, you can retrieve the AccessToken I mentionned with another Graph API call.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to be using the facebook sdk, rather than glomming together urls by yourself:
something like

```
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'email',
  'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri
 );
 $dialog_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

Will give you a link to pop up the dialog.  Then, on the redirected page,

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
echo $user_profile['email'];
```

Docs are [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/)